# FloatingActionButton different in Drawers

Tags: android, android-studio, floating-action-button

I'm using the navigationdrawer layout and I'm Trying to get a different function for the FloatingActionButton for each drawer.
So I thought I could create a FAB for each drawer but if I click the Button nothing happens.

Heres my DrawerFragment.java

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View floating = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hauptgerichte,null);
        FloatingActionButton fab_hauptgericht = floating.findViewById(R.id.fab_hauptgericht);
        fab_hauptgericht.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AddMealActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Not sure if you need anything else

Comment: What does it mean "different function for the FloatingActionButton for each drawer" ?

Comment: I will be having three different lists, one in each drawer Fragment. I wanted the Button to add a object to the list depending on what drawer I've opened. I hope that answers your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a public method in MainActivity and invoke that method in any Fragment. You not need to add a FloatingActionButton in every Fragment, just use the default Activity FloatingActionButton.

```
// first declare the FAB in MainActivity:
 FloatingActionButton fab;

// inside in onCreate:
  fab = findViewById(R.id.your_xml_fab_id);

// and create a public method in Main Activity the return the fab:

 public FloatingActionButton getFab() {
    return fab;
}


// instantiate the FAB inside onCreateView from Fragment:

 fab = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getFab();
 //fab.show();  // if you need to show and hide it in any fragment, you should add this at every fragment
 //fab.hide();


// add a listener in onActivityCreated from Fragment:

 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        // your function
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like this is working, I could only test it on one Fragment but that works perfect! I'll test it on more Fragments later. Thanks